# Android: Place a FAB between navigation header and navigation menu inside DrawerLayout

Tags: android, xml, layout, floating-action-button, drawerlayout

I'm trying to place a `FloatingActionButton` just between two views inside a `DrawerLayout` as below:

[image]

I either end up placing it at the very bottom of the `NavigationHeader` or at the very top of the `NavigationMenu`.
Here is the XML layout (the standard one created by Android Studio):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_main"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Is it possible to do so through XML only? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Yeah, that can be done in XML, but you'll probably have to modify the given setup a bit. I'd probably do [something like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rNUeYpAn_pZdli8E4aCHiyKUsSA-j_qg/view?usp=sharing), which splits the header from the `NavigationView` and sticks them both in another `ViewGroup` where we can more easily position the `FAB` relative to them. Doesn't necessarily have to be exactly like that; the main idea there is that the drawer can be anything, really; it doesn't have to be a `<NavigationView>` specifically.

Comment: Hello @MikeM., I made a quick test and it actually worked. Thank you for the suggestions!